# Merge on any value in a column of a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to merge on any column in the 'Unit" column of the following;

```
from pandas import DataFrame
import pandas as pd 
import difflib

df1 = DataFrame([[1,'034567','Foo'],
                 [2,'1cd2346','Bar']], 
                columns=['UID','Unit','Name'])

df2 = DataFrame([['SellTEST','0ab1234567,034567'],
                 ['superVAR','1cd2346']], 
                columns=['Seller', 'Unit'])

merge2_df = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['Unit'], how='left')
merge2
```

This results in a NaN value:

```
    UID     Unit    Name    Seller
0   1     034567    Foo     NaN
1   2     1cd2346   Bar     superVAR
```

When what I want to see is:

```
    UID     Unit    Name    Seller
0   1     034567    Foo     SellTEST
1   2     1cd2346   Bar     superVAR
```

I'm importing the data from a CSV so, some of the fields will contain more than one value of 'Unit'. Ideally, I'd like to be able to handle this during a merge. Any suggestions?

Comment: You will get NaN because the first Unit in df2 is not '034567', instead it is '0ab1234567,034567'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to split your `Unit` data into singular rows in `df2`. For example, `0ab1234567,034567` row would go into rows. After which you can apply `pd.merge`.

```
In [112]: df2split = pd.DataFrame(df2['Unit'].str.split(',').tolist(),
                                  index=df2['Seller']).stack()

In [113]: df2split = df2split.reset_index()[[0, 'Seller']]

In [114]: df2split.columns = ['Unit', 'Seller']

In [115]: df2split
Out[115]:
         Unit    Seller
0  0ab1234567  SellTEST
1      034567  SellTEST
2     1cd2346  superVAR

In [116]: pd.merge(df1, df2split, on=['Unit'], how='left')
Out[116]:
   UID     Unit Name    Seller
0    1   034567  Foo  SellTEST
1    2  1cd2346  Bar  superVAR
```

Comment: That's great! Works like a charm - thank you. How would we achieve the same results if df2 had more than two columns? I would suspect that the additional columns would be dropped.